# Debugging a potential integer overflow when using a batch submission system?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pbs

so here is my problem. I understand it is not a very well-asked question but that's part of the reason why I'm asking: how to even go about looking for help here?

So I run some piece of code written in Python. The main process spawns a few other processes using the multiprocessing module. Once these processes finish, they send their results over a pipe to the main process. What they send is basically some numpy arrays and floats.

There is also an input data set that varies in size and that is split into chunks and given to each of the worker processes. For small to moderate sizes everything works fine. When the number of data points is on the order of 1,000,000 however, something breaks down.

Before I paste the error message let me also add, that I run it all on a system that's using a PBS scheduler. That's why I find it hard to debug it: I cannot just use pdb and also it takes several hours before the error is produced.

Anyway, here is the error message, could you give me any hints how to go about fixing it? What can be wrong? Or what more information should I include in this question?

```
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/glade/u/home/mjurek/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyMRA/MRANode.py", line 102, in __init__
    pipe.send(self)
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 393, in _send_bytes
    header = struct.pack("!i", n)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/glade/u/home/mjurek/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyMRA/MRANode.py", line 102, in __init__
    pipe.send(self)
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.6.2/gnu/6.3.0/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 393, in _send_bytes
    header = struct.pack("!i", n)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation in `multiprocessing` -- the data you're trying to send is evidently larger than 2 GB, so the length of the resulting pickled string doesn't fit in a 32-bit integer (which is the exception you're getting). You should use shared memory to transfer it instead of passing it as an argument (which pickles it).

See [issue #17560 on the bug tracker.](https://bugs.python.org/issue17560)